# Blockchain android app did a stupid thing!

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

First of all, Sorry for my terrible English!

On Sep 24 i installed the BLockchain.info android app, before that, i signed up in their web application and made my account strong with 2-step-verification and wallet recovery phrase.

When i used the app, i logged in first time and it wants my verification(email and phone number 2FA), I just fill them and wait for app, but after it all of my bitcoins send to another address without my confirmation ( the address is 16hUh5k9V41EMzcuYW3kmkTCzyqju7RXr1 and yesterday had a another transaction ).

So what's going on exactly?

Their support says it must be hackers or malware, but how? It was their app.
After all, i just installed the app on 3 different devices, each of them shows the same picture in attachment with same address.

Please help me, and tell me what i must do?

Really, I'm SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH!

[image]

Comment: Isn't 16hUh5k9V41EMzcuYW3kmkTCzyqju7RXr1  your bc.i address?

Comment: No, i never seen this address!
I checked it, it has a lot of transactions.

Comment: Where did you get the application? Seems to me that it is fake app.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=piuk.blockchain.android
I'm thinking like u, but the app had their database info including my email, my phone number

Comment: Can i find email or owner name or anything that can help me from this address?

Answer (score 1):

It was my fault. What a stupid who i am. I'm really sorry.
It is fake application:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android1.blockchain.piuk.bitcoinwallet

Report application to google If you can to prevent from another SCAM.
Thank You.